# Row selection doesn't work on first tap after scroll in a non-bouncing UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Basically the problem I'm seeing seems like an Apple bug. The problem is after scrolling the table, the first tap on any row only highlights it. A second tap is needed to actually select or deselect it. I noticed that this problem happens most of the time. Very few times it will work as expected, but I haven't noticed any pattern as to when it works.

This issue only happens if `theTableView.bounces = NO;` otherwise, it works perfectly.

I verified this by implementing the appropriate delegate methods.

First tap on any row after scrolling, I get these call backs

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Subsequent taps on the same or a different row after scrolling, I get these call backs

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

//then

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//or
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I have seen other similar questions, but all of them are using a table inside another scroll view, which isn't the case here.

Has anyone found a fix or a workaround for this? I tried on iOS 7.0 ... 8.2 and the problem is present on all of them.

Thanks!

Comment: `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: @UmangBista Either depending on the current selection state of the row. But the problem is the same whether you are trying to select or deselect.

Comment: Well what I'll say is a shot in the dark, but once I had a similar problem, was related with the fact that I was not calling the [super prepareForReuse] when I override that method on my custom cell. Check it please.

Comment: @NunoVinhas  Cell reuse was my first suspect too. But this problem happens to all cells including ones that haven't been reused since last scroll. Also it happens even when I'm not using a custom cell class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot more testing, I found that the problem happens when the table's `contentOffset.y` reaches maximum value or 0. So I created my own "bouncing effect" but on a much smaller scale by implementing `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` in the table view's delegate as follows:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    targetContentOffset->y = MAX(targetContentOffset->y -1, 1);
}
```

With that in place, the problem disappeared. It's a workaround but works like a charm!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48021293/2556498) is a Swift 4 version of your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @YJChoi Thank you!

Comment: Alas this doesn't work in iOS 13. If you have a UITableViewController with a large title, the title and content offset are completely screwed up. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 syntax of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29160527/2556498):

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.pointee.y = max(targetContentOffset.pointee.y - 1, 1)
}
```